# Joining tables in RedQueryBuilder

Tags: javascript, wai-aria, redquerybuilder

Is there a way to select more than one table in RedQueryBuilder ?

The context is :

I need to provide an easy way to help blind people to do some queries.

Thanks for the help =)

Comment: RedQueryBuilder can do joins. So if you tell it about your tables and FKs between them your users can search across the tables. Is that what you mean? I'd love it if your application worked out. Please raise any bugs on the github page, they would get to the top quickly!

Comment: So you're meaning that the relations are handmades ? I'm a bit stuck with the declarations of FK in your example. I understood the meaning of such a declaration but it's not clear enough for me. 
Is the format JSON style or sort of ?

Anyway thanks for you help =)

Comment: It is up to you how they are generated. My uses I generate them on the server. Can transport them as JSON but for JavaScript version you just pass it a JavaScript configuration object. http://0-6-0.redquerybuilder.appspot.com/docs/jsdoc/symbols/ForeignKey.html is the object you need to create and attach to the parent table http://0-6-0.redquerybuilder.appspot.com/docs/jsdoc/symbols/Table.html   Hmmm. pkColumnNames is not very clear.  Please raise a bug if too confusing.

Comment: Thanks for these advice, i'll try it tomorrow morning. If i get stuck, i'll put a ticket on the github page. 

Is the 'pkColumnName' like the fkname on the related table in a common sql declaration?

This project is a bit hard to modify without reading some documentation, but it could be really useful. I saw that you put some ARIA statements in the html code, that's great =)

Comment: pkColumnName is the column in the referencing table. So a really poor choice of name. I've raised a ticket to fix it https://github.com/salk31/RedQueryBuilder/issues/11 but will keep backwards compatibility. I don't think I added any ARIA, all came with the framework. I am a big ARIA fan though and will be very happy to fill any gaps.

Comment: Ok, i'll check it, what kind of framework is?

Comment: GWT http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideA11y.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RedQueryBuilder can do definitely do joins.

You need to tell it about the foreign keys between the tables.

The property names for this will change in 0.6.0 but will maintain backwards compatibility.

Please see https://github.com/salk31/RedQueryBuilder/issues/11 for discussion about the renaming.

Personally I'd be incredibly happy if your app could help partially sighted people.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, l'll do it this evening. The join concept is clearer than before.